# Accessing and retrieving birthday list from the Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I am new to android development. I am developing a event reminder application in which I want to get birthday list from the Facebook and store it into data base.

I could not find a way to get the job done. Plz help..

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a Graph API >= v2.0 app (meaning created later than April 30th 2014), then you'll not be ablte to request the friends data, beacause those permissions have been removed.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions

Comment: ooh ok.. Is there any other way to get the information?

Comment: No. You can't access the data via the Graph API, how should this work then?

Comment: If I use Facebook sdk is it possible to retrieve the info?

Comment: No. Read the link I posted.